# How to define a method only for one client and restrict access to other clients?

Tags: c#, oop

I was asked this in an interview. Say I have a dll (or a class) with multiple methods that is used by 10 clients. Now one of the clients needs to change a method and add a new method to the class. How can this be achieved without the other clients accessing the new method?

Comment: New version of library? Because *"change a method"* is ouch (if it's a signature). Other clients should keep using older version.

Comment: It has to be without the other clients having to make any changes.

Comment: Give them a client specific subclass that overrides one method and adds another?  Release a client specific/new version with the changes?  What are the other constraints?

Comment: one of the clients needs to change a method => change how, signature change or body change only?

Comment: Honestly, I am not very sure if he meant only the signature change or the body. Signature change could probably be achieved by polymorphism??

Comment: There are no other constraints. Just that the other clients should not be able to access the new method.

Comment: Well, this could be achieved by introducing derived class and adding this new method there. New clients can work with derived class whilst others can still work with base, that doesn't contain the method. You can read about SOLID principles, and especially about Open/Closed principle : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Comment: @tolanj: client specific subclass, like how? A new class to be derived and provide access to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you shoud create a new class which is derived from the original class and has an additional fuctionality. For example:

```
public class OriginalClass 
{
    public int SomeOriginalMethod() { }
}

public class YourNewClass : OriginalClass
{
    public int SomeNewMethod() { }
}
```

There are two benifits there. Your client will obtain new functionality and other clients will still use your original class. If you would like to *limit* access to new functioanlity you can add new methods as`internal` in your original class and use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to provide an access only for clients you want

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional compiles so that the code remains the same you just use a compile flag to change it such as

```
#if CLIENTA
/* client a code here */
#else
/* the other version of the code for not client a */
#endif
```

Comment: I don't think this is what was expected... It has to be something related to OOP concepts

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your class needs to expose a new method and change the behavior of an existing method for one client, but not for the others.

A simple way to achieve that would be to ship a different version of the assembly containing your class. As others have suggested, you could use conditional compilation or simply implement the required changes in an assembly with different version numbers. In this scenario, your other, less demanding, clients would use the old version of the assembly that does not contain these changes.

Of course you may well be required to ship the same version of your assembly/class to all of your clients. In that case, one way you could solve the problem is to make your class *explicitly implement* a new interface that would be used only by your demanding client. Your code would look something like this:

```
// encapsulates changes requested by the client
public interface INew
{
    void DoNewStuff();
    int Foo();
}

public class ExistingClass : INew
{
    public int Foo() { /*the old implementation of Foo()*/ }

    // Changes go here:
    void INew.DoNewStuff() { /*implementation of the new method*/ }
    int INew.Foo() {/*the new implementation of Foo()*/}
}
```

Here, the method `DoNewStuff()` and the new implementation of an existing method `Foo()` would not be visible to the caller, unless they first cast your class to the `INew` interface, like this:

```
ExistingClass ex = new ExistingClass();
INew n = ex as INew;
n.DoNewStuff();
n.Foo(); // calls the new implementation of Foo()
```

This approach has two potentially significant drawbacks, however: 1) you would have to coerce the client into adopting the new way of using your class, as demonstrated above; 2) it does not exactly prevent your other clients from using the new methods (but at least it does not interfere with them using your class in the old way). It is a bit unclear from the question whether these two are really significant, so this approach may well be what the interviewers were asking for.

Comment: How is this better than deriving a new class and asking the demanding client to create its object as suggested in Sergey's answer?

Comment: @stylojack_10 It could be better or worse, depending on actual circumstances. One reason you might prefer this approach is if you want to keep your class ``sealed`` to forbid clients from inheriting from it, thus preventing the brittle base class problem.